# Monkhorst – Pack sampling: How many k points one should take

Tags: density-functional-theory, k-points, convergence-test

Reference: Density Functional Theory: A Practical Introduction, David Sholl, Janice A. Steckel, Chapter 3, Page No. 59

> A useful rule of thumb is that calculations that have similar
> densities of k points in reciprocal space will have similar levels of
> convergence. This rule of thumb suggests that using 8x8x2k points
> would give reasonable convergence, where the three numbers  refer to
> the number of k points along the reciprocal lattice vectors $b_1$ ,
> $b_2$ , and $b_3$ , respectively. You should check from the definition
> of the reciprocal lattice vectors that this choice for the k points
> will define a set of k points with equal density in each direction in
> reciprocal space.

I didn't understand what the author wants to convey. Prior to this paragraph, he talks about how many k-points one should take (**Monkhorst – Pack sampling**) during calculation. Gives an example of bulk Cu which contains 16 atoms in its supercell with lattice vectors given by,

$$
\vec{a}_1 = a(1, 0, 0), \quad \vec{a}_2 = a(0, 1, 0), \quad \vec{a}_3 = a(0, 0, 4) 
$$

How does the author figure the optimal number of k-points and how does he justify his findings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The author does this by saying that we need 8 k-points along each lattice direction with unit length. And since one of the lattice vectors is 4 times longer it needs $1/4$ of the k-points. Remember that in reciprocal space the length of the $b_i$ vectors are (in orthogonal lattices) $b_i=1/a_i$. And to sample with reciprocal vectors with the same density you can infer the number of k-points.

In this case $|a_1|=|a_2|=|a_3|/4$, and in reciprocal space we have $|b_1| =|b_2|=4|b_3|$.

As an example, consider a 1D chain with lattice constant $a$. You sample this with $N_k$ k-points. Now take the same 1D chain and double it to $a'=2a$. To sample exactly the same k-points in reciprocal space you need only $N_k/2$ k-points in the $a'$ system.

So say the lattice is made twice as big along the $a_1$, then you would halve the number of k-points

Comment: It simply means you are preserving the the density of the points. Am I right?

Comment: Isn't the equation should be $|a_1|=|a_2|=4 |a_3| \implies 4|b_1| =4|b_2|=|b_3|$?

Comment: Sorry for the typo, see my correction. And yes, you are preserving the density of points.